# Entity Framework Core how to make Any Async?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
    public async Task<bool> IsParagemOnGoingAsync(int registoId)
    {
       return await _context.ParagensRegistos
           .Where(pr => pr.RegistoId == registoId)
           .Any(pr => pr.HoraFim == null);
    }
```

how can i make this async? I can't find anythig on google...

**EDIT**

I knew about AnyAsync();

I tried like multiple times and never had intellisense to add the reference.

Comment: Use `AnyAsync()`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.anyasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/async

Comment: Weird, i tried this but i was getting no options to add it

Comment: By convention, we append "Async" to methods with the `async` modifier. So in this case, it is `AnyAsync`. You also need to consider the namespace for extension methods like this, so make sure you have `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`.

Comment: No need to use `where()` you can just use any/anyasync `.AnyAsync(pr => pr.RegistoId == registoId &&  pr.HoraFim == null);`

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if i could filter using Any and compare a value

Answer (score 9):

You can use `AnyAsync()`

```
 public async Task<bool> IsParagemOnGoingAsync(int registoId)
    {
       return await _context.ParagensRegistos
           .Where(pr => pr.RegistoId == registoId)
           .AnyAsync(pr => pr.HoraFim == null);
    }
```

More info on `AnyAsync()` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.anyasync?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions_AnyAsync__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0_System_Boolean___System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

Comment: I swear i tried this like 5 times and never popped the option to use the reference